# idhttp and problem with response encoding

Tags: delphi, encoding, http-headers, indy, idhttp

I have a little problem with `TIdHTTP` in Indy 10.6.2 and Delphi XE8.

I need to get headers from a `GET` response. I do:

```
Try
  SS := TStringStream.Create('');
  newhttp.Get(link,SS);
  html := SS.datastring;
Except end;
SS.free;
```

`html` is loaded correctly, but if I try to read the headers, accented characters are replaced by `?`.

```
Location := newhttp.Response.RawHeaders.Values['location'];
Location := newhttp.Response.Location;
```

Both methods have the same `?` characters in `Location`.

I need to get a download URL with accented characters.  I've also tried:

```
newhttp.Response.RawHeaders.SaveToStream(SS);
```

without success.

My `TIdHTTP` was created with

```
with newhttp do begin
  AllowCookies := True;
  HandleRedirects := False ;
  ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication := False;
  ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 0;
  RedirectMaximum := 15;
  Request.Accept := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8';
  Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate';
  Request.AcceptLanguage := 'it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7';
  Request.ContentEncoding := 'UTF-8';  //in test
  Request.CharSet := 'UTF-8'; //   //in test
  Request.AcceptCharSet := 'UTF-8';  ////in test
  response.CharSet := 'UTF-8';   //in test
  Response.ContentEncoding := 'UTF-8';  //in test
  Response.ContentType := 'text/plain';  //in test
  Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
  readtimeout:=60000;
  Request.UserAgent := MyAgent;
  HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];
  cookiemanager := MyCookie;
end;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: HTTP headers and URLs are not allowed to have **unencoded** non-ASCII characters.  Whoever is sending a `Location` header with accented characters without url-encoding them is violating the HTTP and URL specs. You should report the problem to them so they can fix their server accordingly.

Comment: BTW, you should be creating `SS` above the `Try` instead of inside of it.  Or, get rid of `SS` altogether and use the overloaded version of `TIdHTTP.Get()` that returns a `string`, eg: `html := newhttp.Get(link);` Also, you should not be populating ANY of the `TIdHTTP.Response` properties at all. And you definitely should not be assigning anything to the `TIdHTTP.Request.AcceptEncoding` property if you don't have anything assigned to the `TIdHTTP.Compressor` property. And `UTF-8` is not a valid value for the `TIdHTTP.Request.ContentEncoding` property.

Comment: I know, but if you see there are a lot of "test" to find some solutions...

Sometimes uses html := newhttp.get(link) have a bad characters, using StringStream this problem not appear.

But...if headers and urls are not allowed to have unencoded non-ASCII, how can chrome (or other browsers) do a correctly download?

Comment: Re the `Location` URL, you can set `TIdHTTP.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding` to `IndyTextEncoding_8Bit`, or set `IdGlobal.GIdDefaultTextEncoding` to `enc8Bit`, and then try to parse the raw URL bytes manually. Re the HTML, you are using `TStringStream` without a `TEncoding`, so if the user's locale does not match the server's locale, you will get bad results for non-ASCII characters. The `TIdHTTP.Get()` overload that returns a `string` uses the charset reported in the HTTP response, so if you are still getting bad data from that, the server is not reporting the charset correctly.

Comment: This server seems to have a lot of issues with character encodings. Can you share the actual URL that you are accessing?